# Raspberry Pi SPI and interbyte delay

Tags: spi

I've got a position sensor that I need to read out via SPI from the Raspberry Pi. The sensor is a MLX90316, that requires interbyte spacing in the SPI message. Typically, I need something like this (recorded from a Cortex M3 which reads the sensor without problems):

[image: MLX90316 SPI]

As you can see, there is interbyte spacing between the individual bytes. The MLX90316 needs a bit of time to fill the last 2 MISO bytes with the sensor value, after seeing the `0x55` in the first byte. When, I use the spidev driver on the Pi, it generates messages like:

[image: MLX90316 spidev]

While the MOSI part looks a lot similar, the sensor does not get enough time to fill the answer in the last two bytes. So I definitely need the interbyte spacing.

My current solution is to bitbang and use my own enable line to generate the packages with the interbyte spacing as needed. See https://gist.github.com/steviethecat/29d5e0e91dca0080a20c21fda33d7064 for the code. While this works, the load on the Pi is around 45% CPU.

Is there a more efficient solution that is accomplishes the same?  I'd rather use the regular spidev library. I did notice a `.pad` option, but modifying that does not seem to have any effect on the interbyte spacing.

Answer (score 2):

There use to be an inter-byte gap of 1.5 bit times.  This annoyed some people so I think a fix was found to remove it from the main SPI device.

I believe the auxiliary SPI device still has the 1.5 bit time gap.  If that is enough I suggest you use that device.

If you need a different gap you could use [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) waves to generate the needed SPI transaction.  However that would require decent programming ability.  This would allow for much less load than the 45% you mention.